# PowerShell - Passing hashtables to a function

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I'm in the process of writing a CLI for a thing I'm working on, and at various points in the process I want to ask the user for input. Each time I ask the user for input, the questions/answers are likely to be different so I started out with something like:

```bsh
$choices = [Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] @(
    New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription("&Yes","Option Description for Yes")
    New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription("&No","Option Description for No.")
)
$choice = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice("Question Title","Question Text",$choices,1)
```

This works pretty well, but it's a bit clunky when it comes to re-use especially if the number of choices expands.

I want to wrap it in a function that I can call easier - like:

```bsh
$options = @{
            Yes = "Option Description for Yes" 
            No = "Option Description for No"
        }
askQuestion -title "Question Title" -question "Question Text" -options $options
```

So far so good. The bit I'm struggling with is accessing the properties of $options:

```bsh
function askQuestion {
    param (
        [hashtable]$options,
        [string]$title,
        [string]$question
    )
    Write-Host $title -ForegroundColor Cyan
    Write-Host $question -ForegroundColor Cyan

    foreach($option in $options)
    {
        # Do stuff HERE
    }
}
```

If I just access `$option` directly in the foreach, it prints out a table like:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
No                             Option Description for No
Yes                            Option Description for Yes
```

If I try accessing `$option.Name` or .Value it doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong with this please?

Comment: use `$TableName['KeyName']` to access a value paired with that key.

Comment: @lee_Dailey thanks - that does work, but presumes a key structure that's the same - in my scenario the answers to questions are likely to change regularly so the key won't be predictable.

Comment: then how are you going to know what to do with whatever you receive? `$TableName.Keys` will give you the key names ... but then you still need to know what they are _for_. [*grin*]

Comment: @lee_Dailey - capturing the output of PromptForChoice ... it returns the index of the choice so you can build the logic for what to do where it matters, rather than in the askQuestion function :)

Comment: ah ... thank you for the clarification! i think that the `.GetEnumerator()` method shown by AdminOfThings is quite good for this, you may also want to look at iterating thru the keys with `$TableName.Keys`. they give very similar results, but get there differently enuf that you may find one or the other more intuitive to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the `GetNumerator()` method to iterate through the hash table entries. Then create a custom message using the format operator `-f`. `$i` here is just something to track a number for each line in the output. This should be fairly dynamic provided your values/descriptions are consistently worded so there are no grammatical/comprehension issues.

```
$i = 1
foreach ($option in $options.GetEnumerator()) {
    "{2}. Enter {0} for {1}" -f $option.key,$option.value,$i++
}
```

Comment: This didn't quite work for me, however it got me close enough to the answer. By using GetEnumerator() I was then able to access $option.key and $option.value which gives me exactly what I needed! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, this is what this finished up looking like:

```bsh
function askQuestion {
    param (
        [hashtable]$options,
        [string]$title,
        [string]$question
    )

    $choices = [Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] @(
        foreach ($option in $options.GetEnumerator()) {
            $selection = $option.key
            $description = $option.value
            New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription("&$selection",$description)
         }
    )
    $choice = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title,$question,$choices,1)
    return
}
```

And it can be called with something like this, where $options is very flexible.

```bsh
$options = @{
    Yes = "Yes Description" 
    No = "No Description"
    Maybe = "Maybe Description"
}

askQuestion -title "Question Title" -question "Question Text" -options $options
```